# Как устроены примитивные типы в Java?

Tags: java, типы, реализация

Типы-обёртки (вроде `Integer`) это классы, которые вполне можно "пощупать" в исходниках и понять как они устроены и работают. Как реализованы примитивные типы на уровне языка?

Comment: Вот хорошая статья. Достаточно интересная и нетяжелая. https://sohabr.net/habr/post/261315/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Честно говоря опасаюсь, что не понимаю суть вопроса, но ответить всё же попробую. Возьмём для примера

```
public class Example {
    public static void test() {
        int i = 69;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
    }
}
```

После компиляции исходный код превратится в class-файл содержащий байткод - инструкции виртуальной машины. В частности `int i = 69` превратится в два байткода

```
0: bipush        69
2: istore_0
```

Команда `java Example` запустит виртуальную машину, которая загрузит файл Example.class в память, создаст главный поток и вызовет в нём метод `main`. При создании главного потока в off-heap памяти виртуальной машины для него будет создан стек. В момент вызова метода `test` в этом стеке будет создан фрейм. Каждый фрейм содержит массив 32-битных ячеек для хранения локальных переменных и аргументов метода, а также *стек операндов*. Да-да, стек в стеке. JVM - [стековая виртуальная машина](https://habr.com/company/intel/blog/254793/), в ней стек операндов служит тем же целям, что и регистры в процессоре. Виртуальная машина начнёт выполнять байткод метода с нулевого смещения, по которому расположен опкод `bipush` с операндом 69. Этот опкод поместит константу 69 на вершину стека операндов. Следующий опкод `istore_0` возьмёт элемент с вершины стека операндов и поместит в 1-й элемент массива локальных переменных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Пощупать" релизацию виртуальной машины, выполняющей байткод можно так же в [исходниках](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/hotspot/file/5ab7a67bc155/src/share/vm). Правда, это будет уже C++, а не Java. Посмотреть код интерпретатора, выполняющийся для конкретного опкода, можно [там же](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/hotspot/file/5ab7a67bc155/src/cpu/x86/vm/templateTable_x86.cpp#l407), но он платформозависим и в нём уже будет сплошной ассемблер.